# Batch file if statement with second else

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, dos

i'm having trouble getting this to work:

```
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={yes} (goto :yes) ELSE (goto :invalid) 
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={no} (goto :no) ELSE (goto :invalid)
```

the `if /i {%ANSWER%}=={no} (goto :no) ELSE (goto :invalid)` wont work, only the one for yes will Is there any alternative? i have tried `if NOT` statements also in this similar way and it seems to just cancel each other out(of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it'll go directly to `invalid` because of the `else` in the first `if` statement. Simply your second `if` will never be evaluated.

I suggest to simply remove the first `else`:

```
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={yes} (goto :yes)
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={no} (goto :no) ELSE (goto :invalid)
```

Note that this is equivalent to:

```
IF /i {%ANSWER%} EQU {yes} GOTO yes
IF /i {%ANSWER%} EQU {no} GOTO no

ECHO Ooops, invalid input.
GOTO :EOF

:yes
ECHO You said YES!
GOTO :EOF

:no
ECHO You said NO!
GOTO :EOF
```